# How to centre the root node of a tikz tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tikz code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={text width=2cm, level distance = 2.8cm,level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm}, }] 
\node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Book Thief}\\1939}
 child{ node [text width=2.5cm] {{\em The Great Train Robbery}\\1855} 
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Ross Poldark}\\1782} 
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em A Tale of Two Cities}\\1755}
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Girl with a Pearl Earring}\\1664 }}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
 }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Revenant}\\1823} }
}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe}\\1940}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      child{ node [text width=2.5cm] {{\em The Life of Pi}\\1976}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Gravity's Rainbow}\\1944} }                            }
  }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces the following tree:

[image]

This isn't what I'm looking for - I want the root to be the centre of the page and it's children to be equal amounts to the left and right of it. My root note is currently too far left (this is also true for nodes further down the tree).

How can I enforce a nodes children being equally distant horizontally?

EDIT: example in full context, as sensibly requested, thank you understanding the whole 'wall of code'.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}


\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,text centered,anchor=west,text width=2.4cm]
\tikzstyle{selected}=[draw=red,fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{optional}=[dashed,fill=gray!50]
\tikzset{
>=stealth',
  invis/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=white, very thick,
    text width=4em, 
    minimum height=2em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=5em, 
    minimum height=2em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=4em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=5em, 
    minimum height=2.0em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=7pt,draw=gray!01,ultra thin},
}

%The Books
\begin{figure} 
\tikzstyle{fade}=[dashed,fill=gray!20]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={text width=2cm, level distance = 2.8cm,level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm}, }] 
\node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Book Thief}\\1939}
 child{ node [text width=2.5cm] {{\em The Great Train Robbery}\\1855} 
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Ross Poldark}\\1782} 
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em A Tale of Two Cities}\\1755}
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Girl with a Pearl Earring}\\1664 }}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
 }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Revenant}\\1823} }
}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe}\\1940}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      child{ node [text width=2.5cm] {{\em The Life of Pi}\\1976}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Gravity's Rainbow}\\1944} }                            }
  }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Food}
\label{rewrite} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your preamble may be interfering --would you like to share

Comment: Unlike any other programming languages, it makes a lot of difference if you change the preamble of your document in terms of the output, such as clashing packages or page settings changed by some detail in the code and so on. That's why we need to have a complete example together with the relevant parts of your preamble included. Otherwise we might not be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Sensible - I will pop back shortly with the full example. Just need to go parent.

Comment: @jsbibra  done :)

Comment: @Joe have a look now -- I have deleted some extra code not used --   `invis/.style={`
,   `punktchain/.style={`
,   `element/.style={`
,   `tuborg/.style={decorate}`,  `tubnode/.style=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have placed `anchor=west` in the following definition  -- I feel it should be north as below

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,text centered,anchor=north,text width=2.4cm]
```

the result

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
    decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
    matrix,shapes.symbols}


\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thick,text centered,anchor=north,text width=2.4cm]

%The Books
\begin{figure} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ->,>=stealth',
    level/.style={text width=2cm, level distance = 2.8cm,
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}, 
level 3/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm}, }] 
\node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Book Thief}\\1939}
 child{ node [text width=2.5cm] {{\em The Great Train Robbery}\\1855} 
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Ross Poldark}\\1782} 
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em A Tale of Two Cities}\\1755}
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Girl with a Pearl Earring}\\1664 }}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
 }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Revenant}\\1823} }
}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe}\\1940}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      child{ node [text width=2.5cm] {{\em The Life of Pi}\\1976}
      child{ node[draw=none]  {{}} }
      child{ node[text width=2.5cm]  {{\em Gravity's Rainbow}\\1944} }                            }
  }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Food}
\label{rewrite} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `forest` package:

[image]

(red lines show text border)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shadows}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes style
           draw,
           fill = white, drop shadow,
     text width = 6em, text badly centered,
      inner sep = 2pt,
% tree with fixed angles of edges
                   l sep = 8mm,
                  calign = fixed edge angles,
    calign primary angle = -30,
  calign secondary angle =  37,
       E/.style = {edge={shorten >=1.5em}},
          }
[The Book Thief\\ 1939
    [The Great Train Robbery\\ 1855
        [Ross Poldark\\ 1782
            [A Tale of Two Cities\\ 1755
                [Girl with a Pearl Earring\\ 1664]
                [, coordinate, E]            
            ]
            [The Revenant\\ 1823]
        ]
        [,coordinate, E]
    ]
    [{The Lion, the Witch, and the Wardrobe}\\ 1940
        [,coordinate, E]
        [The Life of Pi\\1976
            [,coordinate, E=1.5]
            [Gravity's Rainbow\\ 1944]
        ]    
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\caption{Food}
\label{rewrite}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tested this - it works perflectly and I learned a lot about the forest package in the process - I accepted the other answer simply because it was a much tighter shorter solution to the problem, but will press the bounty button for this one.

Comment: @Joe, your claims abot shorter solution simple doesn't hold.